# Changing data-content of a button class used in popover

Tags: javascript, button

I have a button class which I am using for twitter popover, my code is as follow:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="chaticon" data-original-title="Users Online" data-content="&lt;a href='#'&gt; OMGTEST &lt;/a&gt;">
```

And what I want to do is to modify the `data-content` via javascript,

Naively I tried to do:

```
document.getElementById("chaticon").data-content = "new content";
```

and it didn't work, any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the built in accessors for HTMLElement.

```
getAttribute(attributeName)
setAttribute(attributeName,newValue);
```

like this:

```
var yourElement = document.getElementById("chaticon");
var dataVal = yourElement.getAttribute("data-content");
var newData = "new data";
yourElement.setAttribute("data-content",newData);
```

here is a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hpfk3/

### edit

You should probably have included jquery and popover in the question instead of just asking about a button element. Since these are available, you can change the content like this:

```
//store chat icon jQuery object
var chatIcon = $("#chaticon");

//change data attribute on element
//change jquery data object content
//call setcontent method
chatIcon.attr("data-content","new data").data('popover').setContent();

//target the popover element and restore its placement definition
chatIcon.data('popover').$tip.addClass(chatIcon.data('popover').options.placement);
```

Comment: I have a quick follow up question, I tried your method and I did see the new content is being changed with alert.  But for some reason the changes is not happening on the popover itself.  My popover code looks like this: ``$("#chaticon").popover({ html: true, placement: 'above' });``  so whenever I hit the button, the alert will show new content, but the content on the page remains as the old content, any idea why?

Comment: using this with a bootstrap popover.  changing the title and content worked for by with your help by div.attr('data-content','body');   div.attr('data-original-title','title');

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the attribute

```
document.getElementById("chaticon").setAttribute('data-content','new content');
```